# How to make input readonly in ckeditor dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, ckeditor

I'm trying to find a way to make input in ckeditor dialog readonly.

I have initialized elements like this:

```
type: 'hbox',
widths: ['25%', '75%'],
children:
    [{
        type: 'text',
        id: 'moduleId',
        label: 'Module',
```

Looking in [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.uiElement.html) I guess the only way is to apply some css style to input?

Comment: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15659

Comment: @LeonardChallis that will make the entire CKEditor instance readonly - the OP wants to make 1 input field on a dialog readonly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution in ckeditor source code. Just need to add this to element initialization

```
onLoad : function()
{
    this.getInputElement().setAttribute( 'readOnly', true );
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I'm having the same problem and was wondering if you could help...  Do I need to add this to the `onLoad` in the **ckeditor/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js** file?  There are two `onLoad` functions already in this file but your code above doesn't seem to do the trick when added here.  Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: search for `id: "txtUrl"` in image.js and append new function for onLoad event, in un-minified version it is on line 192. using Ckditor4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can set an element as disabled on the definition, but you can get the element after the dialog has been loaded and disable it: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.uiElement.html#disable